# october 2009 imac, macbook, mac mini processor

Tags: cpu, macbook, mac

Does anyone know the processor model used in the new imac, macbook, mac mini ?

What I meant is for the 2.26 GHz processor ?  Is it P8400 or P7550 or something else ?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Honestly, the technical specifications are on their website.

Comment: no the cpu model are not in their website.

Answer (score 1):

According to

http://www.123macmini.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=25061

Mac Mini 2.26 GHz - P8400

Mac Mini 2.53 GHz - P8700

Mac Mini 2.66 GHz - P8800

According to

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Mini

Mac Mini 2.26 GHz - P7550

Mac Mini 2.53 GHz - P8700

Mac Mini 2.66 GHz - P9600

Answer (score 0):

iMac:

> 21.5-inch and 27-inch models, one of the following:
>
> - 3.06GHz Intel Core 2 Duo processor with 3MB shared L2 cache
> - 3.33GHz Intel Core 2 Duo processor with 6MB shared L2 cache
>
> 27-inch models only, one of the
>   following:
>
> - 2.66GHz quad-core Intel Core i5 processor with 8MB shared L3 cache;
>     Turbo Boost dynamic performance up to
>     3.2GHz
> - 2.8GHz quad-core Intel Core i7 processor with 8MB shared L3 cache;
>     Turbo Boost dynamic performance up to
>     3.46GHz; Hyper-Threading for up to eight virtual cores

MacBook:

> - 2.26GHz Intel Core 2 Duo processor with 3MB on-chip shared L2 cache
>     running 1:1 with processor speed

Mac Mini:

> - 2.26GHz, 2.53GHz, **or** 2.66GHz Intel Core 2 Duo processor

As you can see, the iMac and Mac Mini have multiple choices to upgrade to.